# Normalise JSON response

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.pedrofonseca.eu/trabalho/projectoslei/api/projects/getByLegislature/XIV"

response = requests.get(url)
json = response.json()

df_final= pd.json_normalize(
    json, 
    record_path =['authors'], 
    meta=['id', 'typeid'],
    errors='ignore'
)
```

This returns a KeyError on `authors`

**Basically I'm having difficulties in extracting the json data, from its three levels, onto a dataframe**

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is happening because some items don't have author properties, we have to filter out items with no authors in the list my brother.

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.pedrofonseca.eu/trabalho/projectoslei/api/projects/getByLegislature/XIV"

response = requests.get(url)
json = response.json()

print(len(json))

def find_item_with_authors(json):
  output = []

  for item in json:
    if 'authors' in item:
      output.append(item)
    
  return output

items_with_authors = list(filter(find_item_with_authors, json))

print(len(items_with_authors))

df_final= pd.json_normalize(
    items_with_authors, 
    record_path =['authors']
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the same goes for ```commissions``` and ```votings```?

Comment: Are they arrays? You can inspect the output of the URL when you download it using postman bro! https://www.postman.com/